# I applied filterset in drf. i didn't know why all the data is returned when i query with a field not in filterset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I don't know why all data is returned when I query with a field that not in FilterSet class

This is my model

```
class TempModel(models.Model):
    md5 = models.CharField()
    sha1 = models.CharField()
```

and following is my filterSet class

```
class TempFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = TempModel
        fields = ("md5")
```

and finally this is my ViewSet

```
class TempViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TempModel.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    serializer_class = TempSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = TempFilter
```

When I make a request

`/temp/?md5=XXXX`, it works very well, but `/temp/?sha1=XXXX`, **it returns all data**.

I think if request not specified fields, **it returns not found.**

I try to define exclude in FilterSet class, but it still not working, How will I solve that problem?

Comment: try change `TempFilter(filters.FilterSet):` to `TempFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):`

Comment: i defined filters like 'from  django_filters import rest_framework as filters', and I did it the way you told me, but it still not working

Comment: can you try simple is `import django_filters`

Answer (score 0):

I found out in [the django-filters documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#filtering-the-primary-qs) that you can override `qs` property in order to filter the primary queryset (the `queryset = TempModel.objects.all()` you declared in the viewset).

```
class TempFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = TempModel
        fields = ("md5")

    @property
    def qs(self):
        queryset = super(TempModel, self).qs
        query_params = self.request.query_params
        if any(query_param not in TempModel.Meta.fields for query_param in query_params):
            return queryset.none()

        return queryset
```

So the code above would return empty queryset if any of the query parameters didn't exist.

Comment: when i exclude sha1, i can't filter with sha1. include and exclude working well. But the real problem is that when filtered into the excluded field, the **entire data is returned**

Comment: yeah, I didn't understand the question the first time. I updated the answer and it should do what you were looking for